# Which gridview is performing the search?

Tags: yii2

I have two gridviews on one page that use the same search model, how can I tell which gridview is  the one submitting a search in the backend?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to give the gridviews different filter urls (https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-gridview#$filterUrl-detail) each with different parameters.